Supervisor fails to run slow-starting process
I have a dotnet application that takes about 30-40 seconds to start and provide stdout output on an Azure Linux VM.  I have used supervisord to control dotnet applications in the past and it has worked well, but it keeps exiting too early (after about 20 seconds) on this one slow-starting app.  I am looking into ways to speed up the application start, but I still need to figure out how to get supervisor to start the app and not prematurely stop its process.
I have tried the startsecs=0 parameter, which from my reading is supposed to do exactly what I want but unfortunately it does not seem to be working.  I have also verified that the command, directory, and other configuration options are correct.  And I verified that the app does indeed take 30-40 seconds to start by running it directly on the command line.
